# A word for entering a submarine

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, differences

I am studying differences between verbs used to enter a vehicle.

Hypothesis number one: for entering a car it it *enter* or *get in*, for entering a bus, train, boat, airplane it is *get on*.

Question: what is it like for a submarine?

Hypothesis number two: it is *get in* to enter a submarine, and *get on* means "get on top of it"

Hypothesis number three: it is *get in* and *get on* for entering the submarine

Comment: I'm nowhere near a submariner, but I would go with *board*.

Comment: *embark*, especially if you're a dog.

Comment: Seem like you're only interested in the different frequencies of "get in" and "get on". You should find some corpora and compare the frequency of "got **in** a/the submarine" versus "got **on** a/the/ submarine". The following ngram doesn't include the verb: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+submarine%2Cin+the+submarine%2C+on+a+submarine%2C+in+a+submarine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20submarine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20submarine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20submarine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20submarine%3B%2Cc0.

Answer (score 3):

The Article [America's Navy: Life on a Sub](https://www.navy.com/navy-life/life-on-a-sub.html#why-live-on-a-sub) starts off:

> If you’re drawn to the possibility of serving and living **on** a U.S.
>   Navy submarine, you should first understand what being a submariner
>   means. (emphasis added).

From this, I infer that **one does not get in (or into)** a submarine. One might go on a sub, but if the term for living inside the sub is to live on it, one goes on, not in.  This article also uses the term **aboard**:

> Nothing compares to the experience of living and working **aboard** a
>   state-of-the-art submarine. (Emphasis added)

This suggests that one **boards** a sub.

The following article, [Confessions of a U.S. Navy Submarine Officer](http://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/confessions-of-a-u-s-navy-submarine-officer-1715113243) tells you a great deal about life on a submarine (and has great pictures), but never once mentions boarding or getting on the sub.

The terms **on board** and **aboard** are used for being **on** the sub:

> People have related serving **onboard** a nuclear submarine to be like
>   serving **on** a long-endurance spaceship, what is daily life like **aboard**
>   a submarine and what social and personal challenges exist there? (Emphasis added)

The closest the article comes to getting on a sub is getting off a sub, when discussing time in port:

> When you do **get off** the boat, a real bed and real food are the highest
>   priority....

From this I conclude that one **gets on** a sub or **boards** a sub, and that there is no special word.

**Appendix**

Unrelated to the OP's question, but too good not to mention:

> Port calls are great even in a country that sucks. When you haven’t
>   felt the sun on your face and you’ve been breathing recycled farts for
>   months, getting on dry land is impossible to describe. FREEDOM!

And click on the reference if only for the magnificent photo of two orcas.

Answer (score 0):

For sea-going vessels, you generally *embark* (and *disembark* when you leave). Less formally, you might *go on-board*.

I'm not aware of any specific verb for going outside on a submarine, but perhaps somebody with a naval background can help with that...

Comment: *Embark* is what the vessel does.

Comment: Could I use the verb embark in the meaning to get on a plane?

Comment: @cornejo - Not if the plane isn't going anywhere.  When you say "I embarked for Chicago" you're saying that you somehow left your original location and at least began a Chicago-bound trip.